# Hostname changed after setting up virtual host in MAMP

Tags: macos, mamp

I have MAMP Pro installed and recently configured a local virtual host called: `test.local`.

Now my OSX terminal prompt says

`test:~ username$`

I just noticed also when an email bounced back the raw header also shows test.local:

`Received: from cpe-111-111-111-111.lns1.lon.somehost.com ([222.222.222.2222]:22222 helo=testhost.local)`

I've tried running...

`scutil --set LocalHostName properHostName`

…but it hasn't had an effect.  Also, if I do override it to the original proper hostname, will there be negative side effects?

Comment: I guess you anonymized the `222.222.222.222`-IP above, but for documentation purpose: It is not a good idea not to use RFC 1918 addresses for local setups. Additionally next time questions like this might be more suitable for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this fixed it:

`sudo hostname properhostname.local`

And I haven't noticed any side-effects yet.  I can still access the virtual host using `testhost.local`.  Works after a MAMP restart also.